# WindowManager.LayoutParams alpha issue

Tags: android, opacity, android-view, alpha, android-windowmanager

In my app, I have a service in which I create a view that I display by using WindowManger :

```
    mFilter = new View(this);
    mFilter.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

    mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT); // PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT works as well

    mWindowManager.addView(mFilter, mParams);
```

**I want to be able to control its opacity dynamically** this way :

```
    mParams.alpha = alpha; // alpha is a float chosen by the user and varying from 0 to 1
    mWindowManager.updateView(mFilter, mParams);
```

The problem is that it works perfectly well on my galaxy s3 under android 4.2.2, on my galaxy ace under android 2.3.6, on an emulator under android 2.3.3 **BUT it fails on my galaxy y under android 2.3.3 : the alpha cannot be set to a value between 1 and 0, so it is either fully transparent (0) or fully opaque (1).**
My questions are : does anyone have the same issue ? Does it occur only with this phone ? Is there a way to solve it or any other wayto change the opacity ?
I've already search the web for a long time but no one seems to have experienced the same thing...
I found a workaround that "half" works by setting directly the opacity of the view :

```
    mFilter.getBackground().setAlpha(alpha); // alpha is an int varying from 0 to 255
```

The problem this time is that on older version of android it works but on api 10 and lower, the view's opacity doesn't update even if I call, `mFilter.postInvalidate()` or `mWindowManager.updateView(mFilter, mParams)`. I have to remove it (`mWindowManager.removeView(mFilter)`) and then add it again but it causes the screen to blink so it is not acceptable...

Comment: can u please share your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It's some kind of a hack, but due to the alpha changes in various Android Versions I often use `AlphaAnimation` to set the opacity of a View, cause this is a reliable way even on older plattforms.

Just give it a try:

```
float alpha = 0.5f;
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
alphaAnimation.setStartTime(0);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(0);
alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
view.setAnimation(alphaAnimation);
view.postInvalidate();`
```

Comment: Your answer worked after some correction but I finally achieved  what I was looking for after adding my view to a `FrameLayout` and then set its opacity with `view.getBackground().setAlpha(alpha)` and then invalidate the view. It doesn't fully answer my problem because I would like to use WindowManger.LayoutParams.alpha... Thank you anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work when a user disables device animations.